# can i use luckybackup to backup entire home dir to 16gb usb drive?

Tags: backup, rdiff-backup

I wonder what backup tool has gui and can do this stress-free, shell-free way? I just want to hit button "backup entire ubuntu os" and it will do it for me..

sort of make a snapshot of all the files.

I want to do this:

- back up ubuntu to usb stick.
- erase ubuntu
- install windows as main os
- restore ubuntu from the backup

Answer (score 1):

LuckyBackup works well for me backing up files from local disks formatted in ext4 to a 1TB NAS and for belt and braces from the first 1TB NAS to a secondary one.

If backing up to a USB device, you will need to ensure the device is properly mounted - perhaps by following the steps in this resource: https://vitux.com/how-to-manually-mount-unmount-a-usb-device-on-ubuntu/

It is very easy to set up and test (in silent mode) to check the effect of the commands you are issuing.

[image]

Comment: @@Graham, thx u , but can i back it up to usb?

Comment: I don't see why not if it is correctly mounted.